# Unable to bevel edges on face of an extruded number file

Tags: modeling, bevel

New to any 3D design! Total novice here!  I have created my SVG and imported that, no problems. This is an item I will be cutting out and he wants the edges beveled. Following all the videos I have found, I'm still stuck. I honestly do not know what im doing!  Any advice much appreciated. I am not trying to smooth and round out front edges, I want then to be a an angle/bevel.

[image: first job]

Comment: Have you tried the bevel modifier? Skip to 2:30 in this video https://youtu.be/JSvGts95S7A

Comment: No had not  thank you!